# indexed_search v. 8: make backend modul Indexing accessible for non admin

Tags: typo3

is there a possibility in TYPO3 LTS 8 to make the backendmodul "Indexing" accessible for non admin users? I miss this module in the access lists in backend user group configuration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible out of the box. As a solution I would propose to override the configuration with a 3rd party extension or applying diff files during composer install (see https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches).